# Vue instance does not pick up shims-vue.d.ts file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, typescript-definitions

I have a Vue file that looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'MyComponentsName',
  methods: {
    doRedirect() {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'another-route' });
    },
  },
});
```

And then in my `shims-vue.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue;
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

  interface VueConstructor {
    $router: VueRouter;
  }

  interface Vue {
    $router: VueRouter;
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following warning: `Property '$router' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, ...>`

From what I understand, my shims should be telling Vue what `$router` is, but that doesn't seem to be happening. The only work around I've come up with is using `((this as any).$router as VueRouter).push()`, but that seems pretty ugly...

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using vue-router you shouldn't be augmenting yourself.

Although

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module '*.vue' {

  export default Vue
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $property1: number;
  }
}
```

Should be the correct way of doing so

Comment: So my syntax looks correct to you? That's what I thought. I wonder why it's not working...

Comment: It doesn't if you look better, Vue is imported on the top. Not in the first declaration

Comment: Oh, I'll try that. Thanks!